# Which article to use and why?

Tags: grammaticality, articles

Which article should I use and why, both seem correct to my senses.

Here I'm talking only about a leg of mine not both.

> 1a) I have ***the*** leg of a footballer.

OR

> 1b) I have ***a*** leg  of a footballer.

Here a person only can have a single body.

> 2a) I have ***the*** body of a supermodel.

OR

> 2b) I have ***a*** body of a supermodel.

Comment: “the body of a” but “a body like a”

Comment: Do you have any idea why it is "incorrect"?

Comment: The leg of a football player and the body of a model—generic nouns representing a class. A body like a supermodel refers to a specific body.

Comment: "A body like a supermodel is a dream for me",here I have generalized it, you can use "a" or "the", "a" simply says any body but of a supermodel and "the" says it as a class.

Comment: A serial killer could have the body of more than one supermodel.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you keep them? Sorry, had to ask that :-)

I think in both cases it is better to use 'the'. The 'the' here does not refer to a particular limb but is used in a generic sense.

**'The giraffe is the tallest of the animals'**

**'I can play the guitar'**

Source: Raymond Murphy, *English Grammar in Use*, p. 150

Comment: I know the generic sense, you can also say "A giraffe is a tall animal" but are my examples considered  "correct" if I use "a" in it?

Comment: In my opinion, they're not. The examples with 'a' sound like you have an extremely unusual hobby. Compare 'I have a head of a giraffe' vs 'I have the head of a giraffe'. In my ear, the former clearly means you're talking about a trophy, whereas the latter refers to the shape of your head.

Comment: So, "I have a body of a supermodel".what's your opinion on this?

Comment: @English--moreexcthanlaws My final opinion is that it means that you are storing a body of a woman in your wine cellar. If you want to say that you look gorgeous - use 'the'.

Comment: Lmao that was a stretch, but when you and your friend are watching a fashion show and then you utter this sentence will it be considered as your "stretch"?

Comment: Me watching a fashion show? Literally, I can't imagine that happening in any possible reality :)

Comment: My point was, contextually anything is possible, but obviously in a normal conversation your "stretch" you stated would have no meaning. I know "the" is the best option here but when I say the sentence out loud with "a" it still indicates the meaning of "the", that's what bothers me.

Comment: As a non-native speaker of EN, unfortunately, I can hardly help you with feelings about what is 'right'. :)  After the discussion, anything starts to sound right to me :)

Comment: @English--moreexcthanlaws Saying "I have a body of a supermodel" by convention and usage (which is all that natural language is, except to some extent for French) means that you have in your posession a supermodel's corpse. If you want to suggest that you are female, 6 feet tall as a minimum, have beautifully formed breasts, hips and buttocks but a BMI of around 16 then you need go say " I have _the_ body of a supermodel. If you insist on using "a" and want to say you are tall and skinny, but want to avoid a visit from the police you need to say "I have _a_ body _like_ a supermodel."

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at a snowclone.

- 'He has the X of a Y'

(where X and Y are suitable nouns/NPs, and 'he' can be a noun, 'she', 'it' or with verb adjustment 'I', 'you' or more rarely 'they').

The articles are respectively always 'the', and almost always 'a/an' though this may be replaced by the zero article if the second N/NP is plural.

'Mind' may be the original noun X, though 'body' is a close contender.

- "My brother has the mind of a scientist or a philosopher and yet he elects to be a detective." ['Sherlock'].
- 'This guy has the mind of an 11-year-old.'
- 'She has the body of an angel.'

Individual body parts for X in examples showing a closer relationship are rather unusual, though expressions like

- You have your mother's eyes, Harry.'

are of course common. But note that here 'inherited' rather than 'of a type / standard that is usually associated with' is the stronger semantic relation.

Used – let's say morefiguratively – this restriction is less binding:

- "I have the eyes of a hawk and the ears of a fox." [Gimli; The Fellowship of the Ring; Tolkien; film adaptation]

But 'I have the leg of a footballer' sounds unusual. 'He has the legs of a fellwalker' seems perhaps more suitable. The comparator is perhaps more likely, and most people have two legs – and while using a single example ('She has a good eye for a bargain') to refer to a plurality is common, novel examples ('the finger of a pianist'; 'the leg of a footballer') don't sound natural.